# how to display data from form as summary?

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I have a small form with these fields:

```
<input required="" type="text" data-field="fld_727838" class=" form-control" id="fld_727838_1" name="fld_727838" value="" data-type="text" aria-required="true" aria-labelledby="fld_727838Label">

<input required="" type="text" data-field="fld_171035" class=" form-control" id="fld_171035_1" name="fld_171035" value="" data-type="text" aria-required="true" aria-labelledby="fld_171035Label">

<input type="tel" data-field="fld_2575575" class="form-control parsely-error" id="fld_2575575_1" name="fld_2575575" value="" data-type="phone_better" aria-labelledby="fld_2575575Label" autocomplete="off" placeholder="(201) 555-0123">
```

I want to create a summary that gathers the info the user has input, like this:

- your name is: (display what the user First Name field is)
- your last is: (display what the user last name is)
- your phone number is: (display what the user cell # has input)

how do i do it?

Comment: So what you tried so far? And why do you have `data-field`, `data-type`, attributes?

Comment: You wish a confirm before submit... Right? When do you want the "summary" to be displayed? And where?

Comment: I think i need to explain a few things: these fields that you see above are from the "inspect" option in Chrome; the fields themselves were added in WordPress using a plugin to create a form, so i don't know why there are those attributes.  What i would like to have is a summary of the answers given by the user, something on the last page for the user to check if there are errors, so he can correct them before submitting the form.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example using some jQuery functions. It looks like you are using some form building plugin or framework that is adding some unhelpful ids and data attributes, but we'll just ignore them. You said you weren't sure what to even look up so I'll explain each line of the javascript/jQuery.

Attach an event handler function that gets called every time you remove focus from (blur) an input field.

```
$('input').on('blur', function() {
```

Start with a blank string.

```
let summary = '';
```

Loop through all of the inputs

```
$('input').each( function() {
```

Get the value of this input and add it to the string with a space at the end.

```
    summary += $(this).val() + ' ';
```

This is the end of the inputs loop

```
});
```

Set the text in your html of the element with id="summary" to the string we built.

```
$('#summary').text(summary);
```

This is the end of the event handler function.

```
});
```

```js
$('input').on('blur', function() {
    let summary = '';
    $('input').each( function() {
        summary += $(this).val() + ' ';
    });
    $('#summary').text(summary);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>Form</h3>

<input required="" type="text" data-field="fld_727838" class=" form-control" id="fld_727838_1" name="fld_727838" value="" data-type="text" aria-required="true" aria-labelledby="fld_727838Label">

<input required="" type="text" data-field="fld_171035" class=" form-control" id="fld_171035_1" name="fld_171035" value="" data-type="text" aria-required="true" aria-labelledby="fld_171035Label">

<input type="tel" data-field="fld_2575575" class="form-control parsely-error" id="fld_2575575_1" name="fld_2575575" value="" data-type="phone_better" aria-labelledby="fld_2575575Label" autocomplete="off" placeholder="(201) 555-0123">

<hr>

<h3>Summary</h3>
<div id="summary"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use  tag in html to gather user input data

```
<form id="myForm">
  <input required="" type="text" data-field="fld_727838" class=" form-control" id="fld_727838_1" name="fld_727838" value="" data-type="text" aria-required="true" aria-labelledby="fld_727838Label">
  <input required="" type="text" data-field="fld_171035" class=" form-control" id="fld_171035_1" name="fld_171035" value="" data-type="text" aria-required="true" aria-labelledby="fld_171035Label">
  <input type="tel" data-field="fld_2575575" class="form-control parsely-error" id="fld_2575575_1" name="fld_2575575" value="" data-type="phone_better" aria-labelledby="fld_2575575Label" autocomplete="off" placeholder="(201) 555-0123">
  <input type="submit">
```

jQuery code

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
  $('#myForm').on('submit',function(){
    alert( $('#fld_727838_1').val() );
  });
});
```

## EDIT:

After knowing the use case you can use onBlur() method

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("name");
  x.value = x.value.toUpperCase();
}
```

```html
Enter your name: <input type="text" id="name" onblur="myFunction()">
```

Comment: How do you know the needed event is `submit`? Are you a bit soothsayer? To answer too fast is often a bad guess...

Comment: @Louys proper way to get data from GUI is via submit.

Comment: No!. OP wants a summary... PROBABLY before submit... In order to change values if something's wrong.

Comment: read the final output he wants. That should be done via submit, thats what i am saying @Louys

Comment: Inputted data can be collected and shown via a panoply of events... Not just submit.

Comment: I know that @Louys, but he wants to display data the to user. So in this scenario, he should go with submit. That's all that i am trying to say. We should not just answer the question but get the use case first

Comment: With `submit`... Yeah, you can show the inputted data.. but too late for a change right? That's why I'M SURE that's not what OP wants. This said... That is still unclear what he wants... That's why I did not anwer yet.

Comment: You are right: i want the user to see a summary BEFORE submitting the form, so that if there is an error it can be changed. I was hoping for something simple since i do know much coding, but from the answers i see above it's a little bit above my skills. Can the same be done in HTML?

Comment: @simplemind i have edited my answer according to your need. You can try the same

Comment: @simplemind i also have added a code snippet so you can test the same. Just after writing your name into input box click outside the input box to trigger onBlur() method

Comment: @DadyByte: thank you for your help, however I am not sure how to use it, likely because i dont know where to add it into the form. I am using a pluging called "caldera Forms" so what i do is to drag and drop fields, but there is not option to create a summary before submitting the form. I can add at the end of the page a HTML box in which HTML code can be run, but not sure how to add the function you gave me (P.S. thank you so much for helping me!)